# writing a function to calculate the mean of columns in a dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have to calculate the mean of the columns in a dataframe by writing a function and then applying it.  I understand that this is easy to do with `mean` and `apply` but I need to write my own function.  I have made many attempts but cannot seem to get this right.  Below are 3 of my attempts.  I am a beginner at R.  I would greatly appreciate any suggestions.

```
mean_fun<-function(x){
  mean_c[i]= sum(x[1:dim(x)],na.rm=TRUE)/length(x[1:dim(x)])
  return(mean_c[i])
}


mean_fun<-function(x){
  for( i in 1:ncol(x)){
    s=sum(x[1:i],na.rm=TRUE)
    l=dim(x[1:i])
    mean_c=s/l
    return (mean_c)
  }


mean_fun<-function(x){
  x=rbind(x,newrow)
  for(i in 1:ncol(x)){
    x[newbottomrownumber,i]=sum[i]/length[i]}
  return(x[1303,])
}
```

Comment: In R, never drag in loops and indices if you can vectorize instead, e.g. `sum(x)/length(x)`. Never write `sum(x[1:dim(x)])`

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that all the columns in your data frame are numeric, here is a tweak of your first function, where x is a vector (a column in mydataframe).

```
mean_fun<-function(x){
    mean_c= sum(x,na.rm=TRUE)/length(!is.na(x))
    return(mean_c)
}

apply(mydataframe,2,mean_fun)
```

Comment: I greatly appreciate the help.  Each column consists of numbers and I am trying to write a function that calculates the mean of each column in a dataframe then apply this function with apply().  So the expected output would be for example: 510, 346, 1062,....   I tried the function modification above but received the output: Error in 1:dim(x) : argument of length 0. Do you have any other suggestions or modifications?

Comment: ok! See my update! I checked it on a data frame and it gives exactly what colMeans gives.

Comment: This is better R idiom. Never drag in loops and indices if you can vectorize instead, e.g. `sum(x)/length(x)`.

Comment: The divisor should be `sum(!is.na(x))`. Like this the result is wrong, apply to `mydataframe <- data.frame(x=c(1, NA))`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example by slightly modifying your second attempt

```
mean_fun<-function(x){
    mean_c = numeric(0)
    for( i in 1:ncol(x)){
        s = sum(x[,i], na.rm=TRUE)
        l = length(x[,i][is.na(x[,i]) == FALSE])
        mean_c[i] = s/l
    }
    return (mean_c)
}
```

**USAGE**

```
mean_fun(mtcars)
# [1]  20.090625   6.187500 230.721875 146.687500   3.596563   3.217250  17.848750   0.437500   0.406250
#[10]   3.687500   2.812500
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not to use `dplyr`?

You can get the mean for all columns in your data.frame using

```
summarise_each(funs(mean))
```

If we apply it to `mtcars`

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% summarise_each(funs(mean))

#       mpg    cyl     disp       hp     drat      wt     qsec     vs      am   gear   carb
#1 20.09062 6.1875 230.7219 146.6875 3.596563 3.21725 17.84875 0.4375 0.40625 3.6875 2.8125
```